# How to render model associations in JSON respond_to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a product model and a kit model through a `KitProducts` join table.

**Product model**

```
has and belongs to many kits
```

**Kit model**

```
has and belongs to many products
```

How can I get an output of my products with their kit_id in my JSON?

```
@products = Product.all

       respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'new', layout: "builder" }
        format.json do
          render json: [
            products: @products
          ]
        end
```

This will give me only the product itself, I need to be able to show their kit info

Desired JSON output:

```
products":[{"id":1,"name":"Test", "kit_id": 1}]
```

I want to be able to do `kit.products` in my JS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the include option in your render call:

Example:

```
render json: @products, include: :kit
```

This will give you the following output:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Test", "kit_id": 1}]
```

If you want to include more than one association, you can pass an array:

```
render json: @products, include: [:kit, :other_association]
```